# Quarkus - Multistage docker build fails with javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to create a multi stage docker build inside a corporate network as [described here](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#multistage-docker) but the build fails at

```
RUN ./mvnw -B org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline
```

with error

```
 > [6/8] RUN ./mvnw -s .mvn/settings.xml -B org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline:
#9 0.890 Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
#9 0.892        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
#9 0.892        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:352)
#9 0.892        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:295)
#9 0.893    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:290)
#9 0.893    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
#9 0.893    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
#
```

Below runs with no issue from a command line.

```
./mvnw -B org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline
```

Thinking it was a maven 3.8 issue which blocks http, I have tried with maven 3.6.3 but still run into the same issue

```
distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip
#distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.8.4/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.zip
```

One of the dependency jar is pulled from the the corporate nexus repo with http.

Any pointers ?

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the missing corporate certificate, fixed the issue

```
## Stage 1 : build with maven builder image with native capabilities
FROM quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel:22.0.0.2-Final-java11 AS build

USER root
# RUN gu install native-image

COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus certs  /tmp/certs
COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus mvnw /code/mvnw
COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus .mvn /code/.mvn
COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus pom.xml /code/

RUN for f in /tmp/certs/* ; \
        do keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts  -storepass changeit -alias `echo $(basename $f)` -noprompt -file $f ; \
    done;

USER quarkus

WORKDIR /code
RUN ./mvnw -B org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:go-offline 
COPY src /code/src
RUN ./mvnw package -Pnative

# Stage 2 : create the docker final image
FROM quay.io/quarkus/quarkus-micro-image:1.0
# FROM quay.io/quarkus/quarkus-micro-image:1.0
WORKDIR /work/
COPY --from=build /code/target/*-runner /work/application

# set up permissions for user `1001`
RUN chmod 775 /work /work/application \
  && chown -R 1001 /work \
  && chmod -R "g+rwX" /work \
  && chown -R 1001:root /work

EXPOSE 9080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```